# Discord.py - passing an argument role functions

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I wanted to create a command, like !iknow @user . A normal verification bot I think. Here's my code, I only pasted the important parts:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def iknow(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)

    unknownrole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name = "Unknown")
    await client.remove_roles(arg, unknownrole)

    knownrole =   discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name = "Verified")
    await client.add_roles(arg, knownrole)
```

(The *Unknown* role is automatically passed when a user joins the server.)

The problem is: I get an error on line 6 (and I think I will get on line 9, too).

> File
>   "/home/archit/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py",
>   line 83, in wrapped
>       ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)   File "mainbot.py", line 6, in iknow
>       await client.remove_roles(arg, unknownrole) AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'

I just started learning python, so please don't bully me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [`Member.remove_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.remove_roles) and [`Member.add_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles).

You can also specify that `arg` must be of type `discord.Member`, which will automatically resolve your mention into the proper `Member` object.

Side note, it's no longer needed to specify `pass_context=True` when creating commands. This is done automatically, and `context` is always the first variable in the command coroutine.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@client.command()
async def iknow(ctx, arg: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(arg)

    unknownrole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Unknown")
    await arg.remove_roles(unknownrole)

    knownrole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Verified")
    await arg.add_roles(knownrole)

client.run('token')
```