# Discord Bot: How to give roles via command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So, this code may look really bad, It's because it's actually bad but I was looking for a similar code for hours and couldn't find one that is working. **I'm a beginner** in this discord bot development and heard that discord requires "renewed" code, and I can't find anything that could help with this problem.

```
@client.command()
async def role(ctx):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, id="id-here")
    await bot.add_roles(member, role)
```

I also tried with an event as well: (not working)

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content == 'give me admin':
        role = get(message.server.roles, id='also id here')
        await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
```

Comment: Try this, specifically the `add_roles` one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61008770/discord-py-passing-an-argument-role-functions/61009028#61009028

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Do you mind if I answer my own question based on your code?

Comment: Not at all, feel free to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the code that Benjin send in the comment section helped me to solve my problem. If you struggling with the same thing as I did this is the code that you should use:

```
@client.command()
async def giverole(ctx, arg: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(arg)
    knownrole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="the name of the role")
    await arg.add_roles(knownrole)
```

- The discord command will look like this: !giverole @mention_user
- credits to : [Discord.py - passing an argument role functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61008770/discord-py-passing-an-argument-role-functions/61009028#61009028)